# Angular/Node/Express app routing error in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

When setting up my angular-fullstack generated app in production I get these routing errors when trying to access /

```
GET http://localhost:9000/partials/schedules/schedules 404 (Not Found)
```

This works fine in development.
Relevant part of my app.js file:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/schedules/schedules',
        controller: 'ScheduleListCtrl'
      })
```

lib/routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  // Server schedule routes
  app.get('/api/schedules',     scheduleCtrl.schedules);

  // All other routes to use Angular routing in app/scripts/app.js
  app.get('/partials/*', index.partials);
  app.get('/*', index.index);
};
```

Comment: can you confirm your file path it seems there is no file at this path...

Comment: Figured it thanks to your comment! We added sub-directories to our partials directory to separate our code, and didn't update the Gruntfile accordingly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)